# embed local Jupyter notebook cells in web browser

Tags: python, web, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a deep learning education website.
I want to embed notebook cells with contents on the page

jupyter notebook itself runs on personal pc and I want to run some simple deep learning code in the notebook cell portion of the web browser.

https://reactjs.org/
It's really just like the Live JSX EDITOR on the React page, 
and I want to run some simple deep learning code
just like a local jupyter notebook coding

Isn't there a good way?

The methods I've searched so far are as follows and only Python code is executed.

- cocalc
- livebook
- TRANSCRYPT
- BRYTHON
- SKULPT
- PYPY.JS
- BATAVIA
- PYODIDE

Comment: [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a JupyterLab and RetroLab (classic notebook style) environment running purely in the browser using a pyodide WASM powered kernel (js and p5 kernels also currently available). It's early days, but single cell functionality has already been raised in the issues list...

Answer (score 2):

One easy and free way to embed a single cell into a webpage is via https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

Check out the embedding API at https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/about.html

This is oriented around the SageMath kernel, but it is using Jupyter and supports advanced Jupyter features like ipywidgets, and you can choose other kernels.

If you search for "sage" in any of the content here http://linear.ups.edu/html/fcla.html then expand it, you'll see examples of the Sage Cell server being used in a typical website.   Also, it's used in hundreds of examples here: https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact

Answer (score 0):

i found the kinder posting. it explain jupyter coding into web browser.

https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/12/18/run-python-code-embedded-in-html-via-a-jupyter-kernel/